# Moderator Tools

Tags: support

Moderator Tools: Now I Haz them.

So, my question to the formal moderators is: what I can do to help? How would the non-moderator users with Moderator Tools access be the most useful to you? Or, should I just peruse the pretty stats, and then go on about my normal business?

I'm not particularly *looking* to perform any moderator tasks, but *do* want to be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Privileges page has [writeup on what moderator tools are and basic workflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

The main change (you will soon notice) is that you will now get flag counter in the top bar (same as edits, but different in color) and you can review those flags to add your close/delete vote or escalate to moderators.

Oh, and congratulations! :) Glad to have you participating!

Comment: I swear that write-up looked different when I looked at it previously. :)

Comment: @Chip yeah, I think they have brushed it up recently